# What is the difference between the Store Comonad and a Representable Store Comonad in functional programming?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, scalaz, comonad

The Representable Store Comonad and the Store Comonad offers similar features... When should we use one over the other, and what are the benefits?

Comment: It's worth noting that in Cats for example `Store` is formally just a specialized `RepresentableStore` (where the representable functor is `I => _`). I don't know the details of the Haskell situation, but I'd guess the only reasons that `adjunction` and `comonad` don't do the same are historical.

Comment: Thanks @TravisBrown! By the way, there is a discussion in Cats on a [PR](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/2704) to introduce the IndexedStore, and whether or not it should be built on top of the `RepresentableStore`, you might have some useful input...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I hadn't seen the PR!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference, here's a quick recap on what they are:

```hs
class {- ... => -} Representable f where
    type Key f
    -- ...

data RepStore f a = RepStore (Key f) (f    a)
data    Store s a =    Store s       (s -> a)
```

Note that in particular

```hs
instance Representable (s -> a) where
    type Key (s -> a) = s
    -- ...
```

and so we have directly that `Store s` and `RepStore (s ->)` are pretty much completely interchangeable. In the other direction, category theory teaches us that all `Representable` functors are isomorphic to functions (with their `Key` as the domain), hence `RepStore f` and `Store (Key f ->)` are isomorphic.

In summary: in most cases, it doesn't really matter which you choose. If you plan to use it only on functions anyway, you might as well use `Store` and benefit from its syntactic lightness; if you wish to use some representable functor that isn't exactly functions (say, memoized functions or something like that), then `RepStore` is an appropriate generalization.